# Is there a meeting place for fraction education stakeholders?

Tags: technology-in-education, students-mistakes, fractions, teachers, struggling-students

Is there a meeting place where all fraction education stakeholders (students, teachers, parents, researchers, fraction software developers) meet and collaborate? If not, do you have an advice on setting up such a place? (And, if you are interested in starting such an endeavor, please, indicate so.)

Details: 
I would like for such a site to capture general principles of and scientific recommendations for teaching fractions off- and online (constructivist framework), as well as best practices; to draw from the past, depict the present conditions, and form the future of fraction education; to serve for people of different backgrounds (cultures, ages, levels incl. remedial and special ed); to arch over platforms for different forms of collaboration; possibly some Intelligent tutoring systems; and, finally, to provide materials for learning and teaching, including working with error, lesson plans, and assessments, and context problems open books, which could be used by all involved parties.

From what I researched to my thesis, there is no such a collaborative place and, I believe, it would be nice if there was one. Examples somewhat close in some feature of the idea in quasi-random order: [Wikiversity](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Primary_mathematics/Fractions) and [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Primary_Mathematics/Fractions) on Primary Mathematics for open editing, [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) for tracking student progress and coaching, [Mathagogy](http://mathagogy.com) and [Friday Institute MOOCs](https://www.mooc-ed.org/) for teacher collaboration, [Edmono](https://www.edmodo.com/) for social network for teachers and students and for teachers group, [Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/) for the student collaboration, [Veritasium](https://www.youtube.com/user/1veritasium) for working with misconceptions, [Polymath](http://polymathprojects.org/) for collaborative exploration, [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) for automatically graded competitive problem solving, [stack overflow](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) for answering questions by community of volunteers, [Scratch website](https://scratch.mit.edu/) for collaborative project based learning, South African [Dr. Math](http://researchspace.csir.co.za/dspace/bitstream/10204/5045/1/Butgereit1_2011.pdf) for free chat with mentors, [Debuggy](http://www.oise.utoronto.ca/aphd/report_writer/Recommendations_Glossary/MATHEMATICS/index.html) and [Bella](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Paula_Durlach/publication/263202753_Reinforcing_Math_Knowledge_by_Immersing_Students_in_a_Simulated_Learning-By-Teaching_Experience/links/546774750cf2397f782be890.pdf) for working with error and learning by teaching, [Craig, Chi, and VanLehn's paper](http://www.public.asu.edu/~mtchi/papers/Craig_Chi_Vanlehn2009.pdf) for collaborative observing a dialogue, [Schwarz's paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247502551_Two_Wrongs_May_Make_a_Right_If_They_Argue_Together) for justifying that two people with wrong opinions can arrive at a right solution, [Scribblar](https://scribblar.com/) for collaborative blackboard, [Skype in the classroom](https://education.microsoft.com/skypeintheclassroom) for safe classrooms' cooperation, [ErrEx](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~bmclaren/pubs/AdamsEtAl-UsingErrExToImproveMathLearningWithWebTutoringSys-CHB2014.pdf) for erroneous examples, [Radix](https://www.radixendeavor.org/) for immersive setting, [SOLE](https://www.theschoolinthecloud.org/) for inquiry learning, [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com) for seeing the demonstrations and automatic answers, [github](https://github.com/) for cooperation on development, [Slate](http://www.slatescience.com/) math and [Math ST](http://web.stmath.com/) for visual game learning, [Fraction Hub](http://fractionhub.weebly.com/) for the teacher side of the idea, [Trojsten](http://trojsten.sk/) for Slovak site on correspondence competitions (many times with proofs; corrected by volunteer university students), [Japanese lesson study](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/suppl/10.1142/6339/suppl_file/6339_chap01.pdf) for improving teacher education, [Teacher's tube](https://www.teachertube.com/) and [TED-Ed](http://ed.ted.com/) for educational videos, [Dan Mayer](https://www.desmos.com/) and [Realistic Math Education](http://www.slideshare.net/jdewaard/what-is-realistic-mathematics-education-national-mathematics-conference-swakopmund) for contextual problems, [Teaching Channel](https://www.teachingchannel.org/) for examples of teaching, [TIMSS](http://timss.bc.edu/timss2011/international-results-mathematics.html) for international comparisons, [Rational Number Project](http://www.cehd.umn.edu/ci/rationalnumberproject/) for in depth exploration in fractions (along with the learning paths, research in [How People Learn](https://books.google.sk/books?id=7v2gRGuxw4sC&pg=PA347&dq=kieren+fractions&hl=sk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKncf0zbbKAhUHpg4KHSg1B38Q6AEITzAH#v=onepage&q=kieren%20fractions&f=false), [Steffe and Olive](http://math.coe.uga.edu/Olive/Preface_CFK.pdf), [Schoenfeld](https://books.google.sk/books?hl=sk&lr=&id=xvHESHH7m5IC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=cognitive%20science%20education%20mathematics&ots=oBQVk72PXl&sig=fmxzEfdqJH6JoUKgDq6WvU1MYGE&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cognitive%20science%20education%20mathematics&f=false), [Siegler](http://www.psy.cmu.edu/~siegler/NCTM.pdf) and [Hejny](http://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED496933.pdf#page=297) and many others), Socratic Questioning (e.g. [Garlikov](http://www.garlikov.com/Soc_Meth.html)), 
[Montessori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montessori_education) for aids and creation within boundaries, Philosophy and History of Fraction and Fraction Education for creating a context, blogs for metacognition, Facebook for messaging and collaboration, twitter for news, google hangout for collaboration "face to face," [unhangout](https://unhangout.media.mit.edu/) for group problem solving, wiki for summarizing the gist of the knowledge and multilingual versions, [teachers pay teachers](https://www.teacherspayteachers.com/) for shared materials,  [Tutormate](http://www.innovationsforlearning.org/tutormate) for virtual volunteer tutoring (in reading), [free math tutoring groups on fb](https://www.facebook.com/groups/freemathtutoring/?fref=ts) and math groups and different sites on tutoring e.g. [helphub](https://helphub.me/).

I am aware to create such a central for learning and teaching would be very demanding, but I think it is important and that it can be slowly done if enough people took part in development. Any ideas on what else there is important to think about or how to start?

Thanks

stanya

P.S. This is my first post and it does not allow me to post links, so I will post them below. Thank you for understanding, and if I made any mistakes, I will be glad if you point them out.

Comment: This seems more like a proposal than a question. Is the idea to create some kind of elaborate social media web site to teach children fractions? If so, then that seems kind of silly. Fractions are just one topic in math.

Comment: I get what you say: it may seem strange why one should target for only one topic. However, there are many books and research projects devoted just to this area, just because proportional reasoning is so crucial to understanding all consequent material and the misconceptions are so hard to untackle. Thus, I believe that concentrating on the rational numbers while keeping in mind the number sense (preceding area) and functions (following area) is sensible and needed, and I see real lack of place where people invested in this could meet and share experiences.

Comment: Have you seen [conceptua math](http://www.conceptuamath.com/)?  This site is wonderful for teaching fractions and for virtual manipulatives.  A great deal of research on fraction education went into this site..

Comment: I have finally found the site that can be modified to fit the model I have in mind. It is called Brilliant.org. @BenCrowell, you were probably right about the site having to cater for more than fractions. I thought it has to be build from scratch, but it is reversely: the platform is ready. @ AmyB thanks for the site, I looked there and it is, indeed, fresh and suitable for the classroom. Thank you both for feedback and ideas.

Comment: @stanyas By now, even in the U.S., fractions are mostly little more than "calls" for procedures yielding decimals. As such I would spend as much time as possible on decimals. And, just in case, see (https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/decimals.html)

Comment: Why restrict ourselves to the fractions? It would probably make sense to create a meeting place for ALL mathematics education stakeholders

Comment: @schremmer  You would propose that the infinite series $0.333...$ is conceptually simpler than taking a whole and dividing it into three equal sized pieces?

Comment: @StevenGubkin Of course not: infinite series are only for Cauchy adepts and addicts. The rest of the world uses decimals to **approximate** because, In real life, "_dividing into three equal sized pieces_" is impossible. E.g. 0.333 is what you get when you carry out the code "1/3 to three decimals". How many decimals is the name of the game. The notation 1/3 = 0.333.... is atrocious. Compare with something like 1/3 = 0.333 + [...] which reads "1/3 equals 0.333 + something too small to matter _here_". If push comes to shove and you _have_ to be  "rigorous", you should then use  o[h^n].

Comment: By the way, have you read Gowers' **What is so wrong with thinking of real numbers as infinite decimals?**? Somewhat relevant is [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073041/what-is-so-wrong-with-thinking-of-real-numbers-as-infinite-decimals]